# Polar coordinates: Orthonormal basis

Tags: kinematics, coordinate-systems, vectors

In polar coordinates we have $r= c(\hat{r})$, where $c$ is the distance of a point from origin, and $r$ is the position vector.

So, what is the use of $\hat{\theta}$ especially given that it is always orthonormal to $\hat{r}$ ?

As an extension: What does the vector $r = a(\hat{r}) + b(\hat{\theta})$ mean at all? Does this mean that $b$ is the magnitude of "radians" the position vector makes in the $x$-$y$ plane? But this sounds absurd.

Furthermore, given that the $\hat{\theta}$ and the $\hat{r}$ vectors are always "moving", how do the coordinate axes of the $\hat{\theta}$ and the $\hat{r}$ plane look like?

Comment: What is your $\hat{\theta}$? An by the way, why don't you use $\vec{\theta}$ and $\vec{r}$ to mark it as a vector??

Comment: One of the two orthonormal basis vectors

Comment: Methinks, you think because polar coordinates use two vectors, that only because of this, the vectors involved must be orthogonal. But $\theta$ is an angle, and not in the same vector space as $\vec r$.

Comment: Then how can you represent any vector in the cartesian plane as a linear combination of \vec{\theta} and \vec{\r}?

Comment: Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system . Unfortunately, there,  $\theta$ is only one-dimensional, so not really a vector. Look also at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system and you will get an idea how this can be extended to higher dimensions.

Comment: Besides, this is more about maths than on physics. This is a friendly site, with mostly friendly users. I didn't do the downvote, and there is only one, uncommented as usual to the cowards.

Comment: Voting to reopen - this is a perfectly clear question about vectors expressed in polar co-ordinates.

Comment: @S_M Although the *position* vector of an object never has a non-zero $\hat \theta$ component, other vectors associated with the object may have a non-zero $\hat \theta$ component, such as the object's velocity or acceleration or force or torque vectors acting on it.

Comment: In terms of the Cartesian basis $\widehat{r}=\cos\theta\widehat{i}+\sin\theta\widehat{j},\,\widehat{\theta}=-\sin\theta\widehat{i}+\cos\theta\widehat{j}$ so $\widehat{r},\,\widehat{\theta},\,\widehat{k}$ is right-handed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only thinking about position vectors - vectors that represent the position of a point relative to the origin. For this type of vector you are correct - the position $\vec r$ of a point is

$\vec r = |\vec r| \hat r = r \hat r$

and so a position vector has no component in the $\hat \theta$ direction.

However, position vectors are not the only type of vector. We can, for example, express the velocity or acceleration of an object as a vector. Or we can represent forces as vectors. All of these other types of vectors may have non-zero components in the $\hat \theta$ direction.

As a concrete example, consider the general velocity vector

$\vec v = \dot {\vec r} = \dot r \hat r + r \dot {\hat r} = \dot r \hat r + r \dot \theta \hat \theta = \dot r \hat r + r \omega \hat \theta$

In general, the $\hat \theta$ component of the velocity vector will not be zero. Indeed, if the object is moving in a circle then $\dot r$ is zero and its velocity vector $r \omega \hat \theta$ is entirely in the $\hat \theta$ direction.

Answer (score 2):

You are making a gigantic mistake.

In flat space, we have a rather important convenience that we implicitly assume is available, namely that we can identify a position with a vector, hence position vector.

Position vector $\vec r=\left|\vec r\right|\hat{\vec r}$ defines both its magnitude and its unit direction vector. It is obvious that this is never going to have a $\hat{\vec\theta}$ component.

*But other vectors can have.* A general other kind of vector may be expressed as $\vec v=a\hat{\vec r}+b\hat{\vec\theta}$ and be understood.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Please, please help me with any source that actually discusses this. I have scoured through books and books, but I am still at a loss to TRULY understand polar coordinates, and what is actually going on.

\vec v=a\hat{\vec r}+b\hat{\vec\theta}

But how do I "translate" the above vector in the cartesian plane. What does "b" mean? Radians?

Comment: That is the thing: Only in Cartesian coördinates can you ever translate vectors that way simply. Even in flat space, but using polar coördinates, the same vector pointing in the same direction will have different components if they are expressed at different places.

Comment: Say you represent a point at r = ar^ in polar vectors, given (r, theta). But how will one represent another point, at the same distance from origin, in the same (r,theta) plane but with a different theta? Both points will "appear" to be r = ar^, but surely they don't coincide.

Comment: @S_M *\vec v=a\hat{\vec r}+b\hat{\vec\theta}* You have to put \$ signs around that MathJax to make it render as $\vec v=a\hat{\vec r}+b\hat{\vec\theta}$. MathJax works in comments.